# How do I drive an external webpage from the "renderer side" of an Electron app?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm new to Electron, and not great at React, so apologies in advance if this is super basic. I'm creating a little Electron desktop app where the user can type in some keywords, select some options etc, then a new window spawns and will perform some actions based on what they selected (e.g. parse some flight options and add a matching flight to the shopping cart). I managed to get a very basic version working by doing something like:

Electron loads the main window with my form and options in it

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ ... options here ... })
mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);
```

My react component has a button in it which sends info to the IPC channel:

```
....
  <button id="sendSyncMsgBtn" onClick={handleClick}>Ping Main Process</button>
...
function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('The button was clicked.');
  ipcRenderer.send(channels.SC_WINDOW, userData);
}
```

Then my Electron "main process" picks up this event and spawns the new window and performs some actions:

```
ipcMain.on(channels.SC_WINDOW, (event) => {
  console.log('Received the event');
  secondWindow = new BrowserWindow({... options here ...});
  secondWindow.loadURL(flightBookerUrl);

  secondWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    let code;
    
    // log just to make sure it's working
    code = `console.log('The code is executed')`;
    secondWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(code);

    // click the "add item" button
    code = `
      var xPathRes = document.evaluate ('//*[@id="add-remove-buttons"]/input', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
      xPathRes.singleNodeValue.click();
    `;
    secondWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(code);

    // click the "checkout now" button
    code = `
      var xPathRes = document.evaluate ('//*[@id="cart"]/a[2]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
      xPathRes.singleNodeValue.click();
    `;
    secondWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(code);
  });
});
```

This seems to more or less work for now, but I keep reading on blogs and tutorials that "you should never control the display from the main process, you should pass the information required to the renderer process and do the actions there instead". My question is - given that my "second window" is opening an external URL that I do not control, how do I give control of it to the renderer process? Is this even possible? I would understand that, if I redirect the second window to another of my React components, I can then use the `render` component of that class to listen to an IPC channel. But how would I do that when I'm opening a URL I'm not actually in charge of? Or, should I have my second window open onto my own React component that simply returns a redirect to the external URL, but can also have some additional functions in it?

Or, should I just ignore the posts that tell me to use the renderer process instead of main process because they're talking about rendering pages you control?

Pulling my hair out on this one - I assume it's so basic that I can't seem to find a good explanation for it by googling (or maybe I'm just googling the wrong keywords), so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: executing javascript is not a proper method to execute a number of lines.

Comment: Why aren't you injecting scripts by `preload`?, looks like this is a auto-check bot. :)

Comment: @tpikachu yes exactly, I am trying to aggregate data from various holiday providers / airlines etc and open the booking page and "book" the flight based on what the user selects. Could you clarify how the code would look if I used `preload` ? I'm already using that to set up the `ipcRenderer` but how does it help me to run my JS checkout code on the renderer side instead of main process side? Or should I just not worry about it?

Comment: You can declare some modules like `Bot_Functions` in this object or class there will be listeners and functions that you need to run on the renderer.

Comment: I believe you are exposing ipcRenderer to renderer like this `window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer` on your preload.

Comment: Just same as this, you can expose `Bot_Functions` as one of the browser API. and use like this

Comment: Once dom-loaded then `await bot.auto_login()` `await bot.auto_select()` like this on your preload.